# DDD - Implementing database focusing on domain isolation

Tags: database-design, domain-driven-design, relational-database

If I have an application using DDD with a few domains, I will want them not to be directly dependent on each other, correct? So, for example, in my domain Car I will have Tire as a value object and not a reference to a domain tire. The same, on this imaginary domain, would happen for a car and its engine.

That way, how do I keep that isolation at a database level? If I used the traditional implementation of a relational database, I would have dependency there, being it kinda controversial.

Also, if you could indicate some article on database implementation as a reflex of a DDD approach, please do so.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you might be mixing the concept of DDD identity with Database identity. If you happen to keep your Tires and Engines in a separate tables they may need an *identity column* but it does not mean that they will have a conceptual *DDD identity*. They can still be Value Objects from DDD perspective (no conceptual identity).

Answer (score 1):

Araujo,

If your database management system supports, you can isolate a lot of tables on schemas just like we do with layered systems that use the object oriented approach.

But remember that Domain Driven Design is for domain modeling inside object oriented applications (not for databases).

Um forte abraço.

Comment: Yes, I'm considering using schemas the way you described. But say I have a table with tires and one with cars. Referencing 4 tires on the car table would go against that isolation. The solution would then be having two tables for tires (assuming I need a domain tire), one for the entities and the other for the tire value object on the car domain, where the relevant tire data would be copied to? I'm trying not to mix DDD with database, but the database will be a consequence, so...